# A connection between homomorphisms and continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, ring-theory

For topological spaces $X,Y$ ; let $C(X,Y)$ denote the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ ;  $C_s(X,Y)$ be the set of all surjective continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ . Let $C_i(X,Y)$ be the set of all injective continuous functions whose inverse restricted from image is also continuous ; $C_h(X,Y)$ denote the set of all homeomorphisms . Similarly for a pair of group/Ring/Field/Module s $X,Y$ ; let $Hom(X,Y) ; Hom_s(X,Y) ; Hom_i(X,Y) ; Aut(X,Y)$ denote the set of all homomorphisms , surjective homomorphisms , injective homomorphisms ; Isomorphisms resp. from $X$ to $Y$ .

Now let $G$ be a Group/Ring/Module/Field equipped with a Topology  such that $Hom_i(G,G)=C_i(G,G)$ ; then is it true that $Hom(G,G)=C(G,G)$ or atleast is it true that $|Hom(G,G)|=|C(G,G)|$ ? If not always in general  true , then for what restrictions on the Topology or the Algebraic structure on $G$ , is this true ? Similar questions can be asked regarding relationships between other pair of sets also . Have these questions  been studied , is there anything in literature ?  Any link or reference would also be very helpful . Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you work with *very* degenerate objects, or without the axiom of choice, I don't see how every endomorphism can be continuous. Injective, or otherwise. But what do I know...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's actually more common than you'd think.  For instance, if $C(X)$ denotes the ring of continuous bounded real-valued functions on a topological space $X$, then any ring-homomorphism $C(X)\to C(Y)$ is continuous with respect to the sup norms on both rings.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : " ... how every endomorphism can be continuous ... " ... do  you mean  this statement assuming $Hom_i(G,G)=C_i(G,G)$ or without assuming it ?

Comment: Eric Wofsey : Can you please give a reference to that claim of yours ?

Comment: A linear map $\frac{d}{dx}:C^1[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ is not continuous if $C^1[0,1]$ is linear normed space with $\sup$-norm

Comment: @JJR : what is your comment directed at ?